# Can anyone help me with what set this bag belongs to? brown door, some flowers, a $100, an envelope

Tags: set-identification

There is a brown door, some flowers, a $100, an envelope

[image: brown door, some flowers, a $100, an envelope]

Answer (score 5):

According to BrickLink, the only set with all of:

- 2 x 2 corner brick in yellow
- wedge plate 3 x 3 in dark bluish grey
- 1 x 8 plate in yellow

is 31108 [Caravan Family Holiday](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=31108-1)

[image: 31108]

Comment: Is that a 1x2x2 brick in white on the left, though? If it is, I have no idea what set this could be. I feel it has to be a panel, but it doesn't totally **look** like a panel to me.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it!

Comment: @RSchulz that is https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=22885&idColor=1 , a 1x2x1 2/3 brick with studs on the side.

Comment: Gah! So it is. I don't know why I didn't just look through all the white pieces.